# C++ error:expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration

Tags: c++

```
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class test
{
public:
    test(){}
    ~test(){}
    enum type
    {
        error = 0
    };
private:
    shared_ptr<map<int, type>> member_ = make_shared<map<int, type>>();//build error
    //shared_ptr<map<type, int>> member_ = make_shared<map<type, int>>();//build ok
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

when i compile program with `"shared_ptr<map<int, type>> member_ = make_shared<map<int, type>>()"`

```
main.cpp:17:63: error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration
     shared_ptr<map<int, type>> member_ = make_shared<map<int, type>>();
                                                               ^
main.cpp:17:67: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘>>’ token
     shared_ptr<map<int, type>> member_ = make_shared<map<int, type>>();
                                                                   ^
main.cpp:17:58: error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be at least 2)
     shared_ptr<map<int, type>> member_ = make_shared<map<int, type>>();
                                                          ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/map:61:0,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_map.h:96:11: note: provided for ‘template<class _Key, class _Tp, class _Compare, class _Alloc> class std::map’
     class map
           ^
main.cpp:17:42: error: parse error in template argument list
     shared_ptr<map<int, type>> member_ = make_shared<map<int, type>>();
                                          ^
main.cpp:17:42: error: cannot resolve overloaded function ‘make_shared’ based on conversion to type ‘std::shared_ptr<std::map<int, test::type> >’
```

Comment: when i compile progrem with "shared_ptr<map<type, int>> member_ = make_shared<map<type, int>>()" is ok , why?

Comment: I can't reproduce this with GCC, Clang, or MSVC on https://gcc.godbolt.org/.

Comment: 1) save the file, compiling the correct file (maybe it’s a phantom artifact of a different file)? 2) are there “invisible unicode characters” (these often won’t copy over)?

Comment: What happens if you use `test::type` instead of `type`?

Comment: What compiler, compiler version and compiler options are you using? Can you check what happens if you rename `type` to `abc` or something more unique? Still you don't have a question in your question. You may read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: i compiling in ubuntu, gcc 5.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you are not supposed to initialize class members like this anyway. The initialization of class members should happen in the class constructor, like so:

```
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class test
{
public:
    test() { member_ = make_shared<map<int, type>>(); }
    ~test() { }
    enum type
    {
        error = 0
    };
private:
    shared_ptr<map<int, type>> member_;
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

This compiles fine even in [Online C++ Compiler](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler) which is the only place we are managing to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yes, initializing a member with `make_shared` _inline_ looks weird. Is it a C++17 feature or what?

Comment: @Tobias Well the code is clearly incomplete so I'm not sure what's the intention behind that  `shared_ptr` either.

Comment: but C++11 allow initialize member inline like this "shared_ptr<map<int, type>> member_ = make_shared<map<int, type>>()" ,eg: int a = 0;

Comment: I suppose so, if I'm not getting any warnings from the compiler, but if it's true it's still weird. Besides, it's good practice to put things where they should be instead of relying on "magic". The initializer is there to for this purpose, so give it the task it was created to do.

Comment: What magic? An inline initializer is just as first-class as a constructor. Your example also assigns rather than initializes. (More correctly, default-initializes, then assigns.)

Comment: Structurally, initializing class members like that gives the idea that they are being initialized "once", rather than for every time a object is instanced. I have no objections to that if they are static members, but for object members this just looks wrong.

Comment: Are you really allowed to run arbitrary functions inline like that? As long as they return such a value of that type?

Comment: I can't say I'm aware of a single language where an inline initializer means it's initialized once, and a number where it initializes per object. At this point, there's a fairly strong convention if nothing else. I can't say I ever intuited that it would be one-time initialization when I first came across it.

Comment: @Tobias, Yes, it can be quite arbitrary. It's like any other initial value you give a variable.

Comment: `Well, you are not supposed to initialize class members like this anyway.` Yes, you are, it's perfectly legal code. And much cleaner that an initializer list. And especially much cleaner than doing it in the body of the constructor as you suggest

Answer (score 1):

Have tried your code with [Online C++ Compiler](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler), got the same errors with `C++`, `C++11`, and `C++14` compatible compilers, but got compiled well with `C++17` compatible compiler. <s>This means that your code is not legal in C++ standards prior to `C++17`</s>. As pointed out by others, the code, however, compiled well on other online compiler sites even with `C++11` and `C++14` standards. So I would guess the errors are due to supported / unsupported features of compilers.

Comment: GCC 5.4 (per the OP) doesn't compile this with C++17. GCC 6.1 compiles it with C++11. Clang also compiles it with C++11. I'm inclined to say it's the compiler, not the language standard.

Comment: According to [the documentation for gcc 5.4](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.4.0/gcc/Standards.html#Standards), it supports C++98 with experimental support for C++11. Member initialization as well as template right angle brackets (`>>`) are new for C++11 and therefore must be explicitly enabled with `-std=c++11`. "The default, if no C++ language dialect options are given, is `-std=gnu++98`."